# Test tmp file edited by external editor

Tags: cucumber, aruba

I have a feature that will open the user's editor (specified in `$EDITOR`) with an empty temporary file somewhere in `/tmp`. The user than has to save this file, and if it has changed content, another command should be run with that temporary file.

```
When I run `app new`
And I the user enters and saves text
Then "another-app --process <tmpfile>" should be run
```

I already have steps to check a command is run, which leaves me with two problems:

1. How do I non-interactively edit this temporary file?
2. How can my cuke know the random tempfile name to check the proper command was run?

Note: I have setup a fakebin solution, so I could set `$EDITOR` to a script that would just output some text to the specified file. This might be a solution for (1), but that still leaves me with (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1** is easy since it is just a command changing a file. Whether it is the editor or `sed` or something else doesn't matter. You could unit test the object calling the command to make sure it runs `$EDITOR path/to/file` but that's not something your acceptance test should care about. **2** is easy too, since Cucucmber doesn't have to know the command that got run. That's a unit test thing. Cucumber should only observe the outside effect (some file was created, some output is shown on the screen, etc).

Let Cucumber observe *what* happens as seen by the user. Let your unit tests check *how* that happens.